# two kind mail.jar with different version after build a war

Tags: grails, war

i have a project where use this jar.

[image]

as i know... after build a war, at folder `WEB-INF/lib` must have :

- mail-1.4.1.jar
- activation-1.1.jar
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.jar

but, in folder `WEB-INF/lib` i see two kind version of mail.jar

[image]

in that folder has mail-1.4.3.jar

why?

Comment: Try running `grails dependency-report` . Maybe there's a dependency pulling in a different version of the mail jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run grails dependecy-report in your project, you will know which jar file or dependency is including these 2 different versions of mail then you just need to exclude it from one of the dependency in BuildConfig.groovy.

Something like following

```
 compile('org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:0.8.2.1') {
            excludes 'slf4j-log4j12'
 }
 compile("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.9.13") {
            excludes 'joda-time'
 }
```